# How to make method that turns number grades into letter grades in Java

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to write a method in Java that turns number grades into letter grades, but there is an error with the returns that I do not understand why. Any input would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Lab26 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public static String letterGrade(double grade) {
        String a = "A";
        String b = "B";
        String c = "C";
        String d = "D";
        String f = "F";
        if (grade <= 100 && grade >= 90) {
            return a;
        } else if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80) {
            return b;
        } else if (grade < 80 && grade >= 70) {
            return c;
        } else if (grade < 70 && grade >= 60) {
            return d;
        } else if (grade < 60) {
            return f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you set grade=101?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you don't return something, when grade is bigger than 100. Since you state, that your method returns a `String` you have to ensure a `String` is returned everytime you call the method (even with invalid arguments as grade >100). Just insert

```
return "Not a Grade!"; //or something similar
```

in the end of the method and you will be fine.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Not all possible scenarios are accounted for.

Comment: @AunteekNaser Yep, and hence the compiler throws an Error. Just check for every possible argument or return something at the end of the method to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

`public static String letterGrade(double grade)` expects a `String` return value in all conditions. In the case when any of the conditions (in the `if-else` block) is not met, you are not returning a `String`.

You need to have an `else` condition at the end which would return a `String` or `null` if you wish.

Something like:

```
if (grade <= 100 && grade >= 90) {
        return a;
    } else if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80) {
        return b;
    } else if (grade < 80 && grade >= 70) {
        return c;
    } else if (grade < 70 && grade >= 60) {
        return d;
    } else if (grade < 60) {
        return f;
    } else {
        return "invalid";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put an else statement in the bottom

```
    if (grade <= 100 && grade >= 90) {
        return a;
    } else if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80) {
        return b;
    } else if (grade < 80 && grade >= 70) {
        return c;
    } else if (grade < 70 && grade >= 60) {
        return d;
    } else if (grade < 60) {
        return f;}
    else
        return "An error has occured. You entered an invalid grade";
```

That should catch your errors.